# 译成 To translate from... into

Tags: translation

大家好，

我想知道怎么说
I translate from English into Chinese.
I interpret from English into Chinese.

My attempts：
我从英文笔译成汉语。
我从英文口译成汉语。

However, I'm unaware of whether it is better to use cong...dao...从。。。到
I saw the use of 成 （and 译成） many times （but not 笔译成）so I think it must be in use. A confirmation would be welcome though.
So should I add 笔译成 biyi, or 口译成 kouyi ? In english it's very important to specify that I don't 翻译 only because it's too vague. Translations are always written and interpretations always oral. Please keep that in mind when giving me your answers.

Comment: 口译、笔译 often used as nouns which can be used to form predicates, see e.g. iciba:替外宾作口译,在两人中间充当口译

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a dispositive marker like 将

> 我将英文译成中文。 我将英文译成中文
>
> 汉语 refers to spoken Chinese; for written Chinese, use 中文

you can use preposition [由 ~ 成] or [从 ~ 成] (they both mean "from ~ to")

> 我将哈利波特由英文译成中文 or simply "我將哈利波特译成中文"
>
> *you can omit '由英文' because we all know Harry Potter is originally an English novel*

翻译 is the standard term for both written translation(笔译) and spoken translation (口译) -- *the terms you cited. In practice, no Chinese would use those terms*.

Native Chinese would not replace 翻译/译 with either 笔译 or 口译 . We can tell it is a written translation or spoken one by looking into the context. If you say a book is translated into Chinese, you don't need to say it is written; When you say the translators in a meeting translate for the heads of state, we know they are translating orally.

Interpreter is called 传译員; to interpret someone's speech in real time is called 传译 or 即时传译

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. That helps a lot ! So, there is no way for me to differ in "I translate from English to Chinese" and "I interpret from English to Chinese“ if I wanna state the difference, i.e. in a website. or should I say : 我由英文翻译成中文。我由英文传译成汉语。?

Comment: @Mat 我将英文翻译成中文 (I translate English into Chinese) ; 我将英语传译 (or 即时传译)成汉语 (I interpret English into Chinese); you use 由 or 从 only when you have an indirect object like 哈利波特 in my example 我将哈利波特由英文译成中文

Comment: Oh yeah my bad! 多谢哥们儿，真感激！You helped a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you say " professional translation from English to Chinese" as a title then? 专业将英文成中文的翻译？

Comment: @Mat " professional English/ Chinese translation " = "专业中英文翻译" ; (it means you can Translate both ways) ; "professional English / Chinese translator" = "专业中英文翻译者" or 中英文翻译专家

Comment: professional English/ Chinese translation  (专业中英文翻译) is a description of your product-- 'translation'; professional English / Chinese translator (专业中英文翻译者/ 中英文翻译专家) is a job title

Comment: Last question: to say from english and chinese to french for example, would it be 专业中英法文翻译？专业中法和英法文翻译？same question goes for the job title.

Comment: @Mat professional English/ Chinese/ French translation (专业中英法文翻译)' is a description of a service; professional English / Chinese/French translator (专业中英法文翻译者/ 中英法文翻译专家) is a job title; However, when you can translate many languages, you  should just call yourself "专业翻译者"  or  "翻译专家" and list all the languages you can translate , e.g. " your name: 翻译专家 (英、法、徳、中、日、韓)

Comment: Alright, awesome! Thanks for all your tips! Really! :) Have a great day!

Comment: @Mat It is the same for description of your service -  "专业翻译 "  (英、法、德、中、日、韓) = "Professional translation" (English, French, German, Chinese, Japanese, Korean)